# group image resources

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list 2 categories (cars and boats) and want to have an image for each item. Is there an easy way that I can appoint an image to the cargroup or boatgroup in resources?

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved this by creating multiple resource files. fairly easy solution thus!